# Understanding how the member function works

Tags: prolog

I am working on a Prolog program.  I am given a bunch of facts in the form   fan(name, list of novels liked). I am writing program that will tell the names of the books that three people, sally, mark and rob have in common without repeating the names of the book. I understand how to get the intersection between two people (shown below), but I don't know how to proceed from here.

```
mutual_novels(Book) :-  
   fan(sally,S),
   fan(mark,M),
   fan(rob,R),
   novel(Book, _),
   member(Book,P),
   member(Book,R).
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the good way, Prolog will unify directly the Book variable, so you only have to add one *member* clause more:

`mutual_novels(Book) :-
   fan(sally,S),
   fan(mark,M),
   fan(rob,R),
   novel(Book, _),
   member(Book,S),
   member(Book,R),
   member(Book,M).`

The predicate will give you only the instances Book that assert it (member of the three lists at the same time).